# Android Change Toolbar Color on Selecting a color from List of Colors Like In Google Calender - Screenshot Attached

Tags: android, colors

I am using `Activity` which extends `AppCompatActivity`. I am trying to select a color from list of colors in the spinner and apply that color for the toolbar. How can I achieve this programatically.

My toolbar is :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

My minSDK is 16  and CompileSDK is 23.

Please see the screenshots;
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since toolbar is a view you can simply change it's background using.

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("hex value of user selected color primary"));
```

And use this to tint status bar.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("hex value of user selected color primary dark"));
    }
```

Store the colour preferred by the user in Storage Preferences. Load it on startup and use it to colour the toolbar from onCreate() method of each activity.